# To get the JSON in required format from Web Service

Tags: c#, javascript, json, highcharts

Below is the JSON data that I am getting,

```
 [{-------------- This should be common opening braces
 "legend":[{"layout":"vertical",
 "floating":"true",
 "bgColour":"#FFFFFF",
 "align":"right",
 "vertical_Align":"top",
 "y":"60",
 "x":"-60"}
 ]
 }-------------- Eliminate this brace
 ,
 {-------------- Eliminate this brace
 "Series":[{"Data":[14,
 14,
 14,
 14,
 18,
 18,
 18,
 18,
 17,
 15,
 13,
 12]
 }
 ]

 }-------------- Eliminate this brace
 ,
 {-------------- Eliminate this brace
 "xAxis":[{"Categories":["Q1 / 2013",
 "Q2 / 2013",
 "Q3 / 2013",
 "Q4 / 2013",
 "Q1 / 2013",
 "Q2 / 2013",
 "Q3 / 2013",
 "Q4 / 2013",
 "Q1 / 2013",
 "Q2 / 2013",
 "Q3 / 2013",
 "Q4 / 2013"
 ]}
 ]}--------------- This should be common closing brace
 ]
```

and below is th JSON format that I want,

```
   { 
  "legend" : [ { "layout" : "vertical" },
    { "floating" : true },
    { "backgroundColor" : "#FFFFFF" },
    { "align" : "right" },
    { "verticalAlign" : "top" },
    { "y" : 60 },
    { "x" : -60 }
    ],
    "series" : [ { "data" : [ 14,
          14,
          14,
          14,
          18,
          18,
          18,
          18,
          17,
          15,
          13,
          12
          ] } ],
     "xAxis" : { "categories" : [ "Q1 / 2013",
           "Q2 / 2013",
           "Q3 / 2013",
           "Q4 / 2013",
           "Q1 / 2013",
           "Q2 / 2013",
           "Q3 / 2013",
           "Q4 / 2013",
           "Q1 / 2013",
           "Q2 / 2013",
           "Q3 / 2013",
           "Q4 / 2013"
            ] }
            }
```

Both are valid JSON,but I want second format to plot the graph in highcharts,

below is my code which get the First one JSON data in file as follow,

```
List<object> modified_listofstrings = new List<object>();
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jSearializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

var obj1=new{
                Data=p_Value
            };
            var obj2 = new { Series = new[] { obj1 } };

             var obj3 = new
             {
                 layout,
                 floating,
                 bgColour,
                 align,
                 vertical_Align,
                 y,
                 x,
             };

             var obj4 = new { legend = new[] { obj3 } };

             var obj5 = new
             {
                 Categories=p_Name
             };

             var obj6 = new { xAxis = new[] { obj5 } };

                           modified_listofstrings.Add(obj4);
                           modified_listofstrings.Add(obj2);
                           modified_listofstrings.Add(obj6);

jSearializer.Serialize(modified_listofstrings);
```

To be precise, my Legend, Series and xAxis are getting encircled in curly braces, I want to eliminate those, How can I do that, any help will be greatly appreciated.. and also atrribute of all legend should be encircled in curly braces as shown in expected output..am I messing with taking object in proper way while passing to serialize..?
Is it possible what I am desiring..??

Comment: look at the tree you want...`Legend` and `Series` and `xAxis` are sibling properties of same object...so don't separate them as different objects in server code

Comment: Actually , I am trying to write in same object but I am not able to do so, I am getting error while coding, can you please update the code in desired way so that I can come to know where exactly I am wrong..please..

Comment: @charlietfl...I got your idea, thanks...one last problem, can you please tell me how can I put curly brace in legend after every attribute and also please answer it separately so that I can check it as answer.

Comment: you should probably check structure needed again....legend should be one object , the way you have it in orginal output...look at demos on highcharts site

Comment: @charlietfl.. the output that I want , in that may be legend is one object in which I need to pass different properties like layout,y,x etc as object then how will I do that, the expected output works in highcharts and I want my resulted output to be same like it to work in highcharts..

Comment: try `legend =obj3` ...I'm not very familiar working with language you are using...work mostly in php and javascript

Comment: @charlietfl... It worked..can you please write it as an another answer so that I can accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

create classes rather than adding up items to object type this will be more efficient and generate right json you want..

from http://json2csharp.com/

```
public class Legend
{
    public string layout { get; set; }
    public bool? floating { get; set; }
    public string backgroundColor { get; set; }
    public string align { get; set; }
    public string verticalAlign { get; set; }
    public int? y { get; set; }
   public int? x { get; set; }
}

   public class Series
{
    public List<int> data { get; set; }
}

public class XAxis
{
    public List<string> categories { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Legend> legend { get; set; }
    public List<Series> series { get; set; }
    public XAxis xAxis { get; set; }
}
```

now add up the objects to this classes and at last serialize RootObject which is your json

copy your json and paste on http://json2csharp.com/ which ll generate classes use that to create objects